# How to restart ngOnInit to update Interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Is there way to restart `ngOnInit()` on change variable

Because I want to restart `ngOnInit()` on change `theme` variable,
this is my code

**Settings.ts**

```
export class SettingsPage implements OnInit{
  phraseColor: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    let tch : {} = {'#3f51b5': 'Blue', '#ff9800': 'Orange'}
    let ColorName =  tch[this.settingsService.theme]; /* here my problem */
    this.phraseColor = ColorName;
  }
  changeTheme(){
    this.settingsService.theme = '#ff9800';
  }
}
```

**Settings.html**

```
<div>Theme is {{ phraseColor }}</div>
<button (click)="changeTheme()">Change language</button>
```

My problem at `phraseColor` variable

Default value of `phraseColor` is **Blue**

when I change `theme` variable using `changeTheme()` It supposed to be the value of `phraseColor` is **Orange**

But no the value of `phraseColor` stay **Blue**

However when I go to any page and return to this page the value of `phraseColor` is **Orange**

**My Question is how to restart `ngOnInit` to update Interpolation**

`theme` variable from this page **SettingsService.ts**

```
export class SettingsService {
  theme: string = '#3f51b5';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is lifecycle hook. It is executed by the framework and isn't supposed to be called manually. The class should be refactored to not require that.

Considering that `settingsService.theme` isn't changed arbitrarily but only with `changeTheme`, values can be updated there:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateColor();
  }

  changeTheme(){
    this.settingsService.theme = '#ff9800';
    this.updateColor();
  }

  updateColor() {
    let tch : {} = {'#3f51b5': 'Blue', '#ff9800': 'Orange'}
    let ColorName =  tch[this.settingsService.theme];
    this.phraseColor = ColorName;
  }
```

If `settingsService.theme` is expected to be changed somewhere else, the service requires RxJS observable/subject in order to to notify the subscribers:

```
export class SettingsService {
  theme: Subject = new BehaviorSubject('#3f51b5'); 
}
```

It can be subscribed in the component:

```
  themeSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.themeSubscription = this.settingsService.theme.subscribe(theme => {
      let tch : {} = {'#3f51b5': 'Blue', '#ff9800': 'Orange'}
      //  immediate value is also available as this.settingsService.theme.value
      let ColorName =  tch[theme];
      this.phraseColor = ColorName;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.themeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  changeTheme(){
    this.settingsService.theme.next('#ff9800');
  }
```

Comment: Hi Estus your code is working, but you have typo in class `BehaviorSubject`