# How to call ngOnInit for the second time?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my `header.component.ts` I'm storing the value and navigating to profile page

```
this.global.profilevalue = value;
this.router.navigate(["/profile"]);
```

And in `profile.component.ts` in `ngOnInit`, I'm comparing that value and calling the corresponding function

```
if(this.global.profilevalue == "abc")
{
    this.abc();
}
else {
    this.efg();
}
```

The above part is working only for the first time, When I'm in `/profile` and clicking on some profile value it is not taking to `ngOnInit` in profile.

How can I access ngOnInit even the route is `/profile`

Comment: You simply don't do it. `ngOnInit` is a very specific part of the angular [lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) that is only called once. You should move your logic somewhere else.

Comment: Actually you can call it as many times as you want. It's just a function. You need to have something to trigger it though. For example
`routeUpdateEvent() { this.ngOnInit(); }` But I would totally recommend not doing that.

Comment: @callback but it is not good practice to call ngOnInit many times, instead we can call some helper functions from ngOnInit and conditionally too as per need.

Comment: @PardeepJain I totally agree that it is not a good practice. I am just arguing about it being **Possible**!

Comment: @callback, no, don't even do that, don't entertain the idea that it's worth considering. It's a function sure, but it has a very specific purpose. If you want to use some logic that's in that method, move it to a purpose-ful method and invoke that method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restart ngOnInit to update Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568623/how-to-restart-ngoninit-to-update-interpolation)

Answer (score 2):

You can But It is not good practice to call ngOnInit many times , instead you can use some function on component load so that you can call that conditionally too

like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initLoad();
}

initLoad() {
  if(this.global.profilevalue == "abc") {
      this.abc();
  } else {
      this.efg();
  }
}
```

Comment: yes right, But you can call `initLoad` method as many times as you want

Comment: Can I call a function in another .ts file from one .ts file

Comment: @Krishna Pardeep solution is good, but if you need to repeat this action in other moments consider also calling the initLoad() function in ngOnChanges() or ngDoCheck(). Please see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks for more info! Hope it will helps!

Comment: @Krishna yes as per Deadpool, you can call this function from anywhere, also, of course, you can call this method anytime.

Comment: Okay. But I need to call an API. If I do like this It is making call continuously